# Front End Plugin for User Management

Tags: plugins, plugin-recommendation, membership

Is there a free plugin that I can use for a membership site which includes user login, registration and profile management all from WordPress front end?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes ... there are lots of plugins for this scenario

You could just enable BuddyPress which gives you a 'social network in a box'

then there are these two plugins

[s2member](http://www.s2member.com/framework/)
[WPMU membership lite](http://premium.wpmudev.org/project/wordpress-membership-lite/)

failing that ... read through the related articles on here for suggestions

Comment: Thanks Damien. I'll check your solution but seems good enough.